# What is the purpose of a read-only input field in HTML?

Tags: html, forms, input

What is the point of having the attribute option to `readonly` for an `input` element in HTML?
As per my understanding, by definition `input` must require write functionality. 
I'm sure there's a meaningful application for `readonly`, I just can't think of one nor have I come across such an application in the many years of browsing the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic sites, it's great to be able to set the input to read only. There are times when you can't currently accept user input, and want to prevent that. So "readonly" gives you a mechanism. It sometimes is used while an async form is submitting, so that the user can't make changes until the page can confirm that the form was submitted successfully. Or sometimes the page needs to do some other work, and doesn't want the user to change the form until it is done.

Also, sometimes your page is displaying data that is in the current case, well, read-only, but you want to keep it a field. For example, maybe you have a profile form with a user name that can't be changed after the first save, or by the particular user. So you can set it to read-only for the cases it can't be changed. The user can still see it, but can't change it.

Read only also gives you much the same benefits of a `hidden` field, except that it's not, well, hidden. So if you need information to be submitted with a form, but don't want the user to change it, then using hidden or read only works well. Both of these approaches let you send extra data to the server that I doesn't make sense for the user to provide, but the server needs to know.

As far as an example, look no further than your stack overflow story preferences. That example is another somewhat common case: a field that is *selectable* but not editable. (However, they chose to not use a real input, just make it look like one, but other times that is not the case)

Answer (score 0):

Read-only fields are usually used to make the user fill in a field and once the user completes the required data, the read-only field can be enabled there.

***The detail is that a form can send a "read-only" field but cannot send a "disabled" field on the form.***